# Hive on Spark NoSuchFileException hive-exec-x.y.z.jar

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I'm getting the following error when trying to use spark as the execution engine:

```
ERROR ClientEndpoint: Exception from cluster was: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/hduser/hive/lib/hive-exec-2.3.2.jar
```

What I see on the console output above the error is the following line:

```
client.SparkClientImpl: Running client driver with argv: /home/hduser/spark/bin/spark-submit --properties-file /tmp/spark-submit.9121550317102424797.properties --class org.apache.hive.spark.client.RemoteDriver /home/hduser/hive/lib/hive-exec-2.3.2.jar --remote-host HADOOP-RESMANAGER --remote-port 41533 --conf hive.spark.client.connect.timeout=1000 --conf hive.spark.client.server.connect.timeout=90000 --conf hive.spark.client.channel.log.level=null --conf hive.spark.client.rpc.max.size=52428800 --conf hive.spark.client.rpc.threads=8 --conf hive.spark.client.secret.bits=256 --conf hive.spark.client.rpc.server.address=null
```

I have a Spark standalone cluster with two nodes. Do I have to install Hive on each node?

The file /home/hduser/hive/lib/hive-exec-2.3.2.jar is on the Hive machine when I'm running the hive command but no on every cluster node.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just tried it, do not have to install Hive client on each node,  install in the node where the Master is

[image: The following figure is an example of my test]

Answer (score 0):

I had to copy the Hive folder in all nodes (same path) to let it work